# How to easily grab an array of children from a batch node by tag

Tags: arrays, cocos2d-iphone, children

I know that I can get an array of all the children of a `CCSpriteBatchNode` by using its `children` property, but can I get an array easily of just the subset of children that share a common tag?

What I do now is:

Get the array of the children of the batch node
Make a new array for the children with the tag of interest
Iterate through the children, and if the individual child has that tag, add it to the new array

Seems kind of cumbersome so I thought there might be a way to to it easily.  If you just want a single child, you can use `getChildByTag` I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way to do it.

However you can (and should) initialize an array with the children that use the same tag in your class, and every time you add a child with that tag you'll also add it to the "childsWithTagX" array. Same for removing. That way you have an always up-to-date separate children array containing only nodes with a given tag.

I think I'll have to add this as a feature to the [Kobold2D Roadmap](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Kobold2D+Roadmap). I needed that a few times already.

Comment: Thanks GamingHorror - I've been thinking that this is the way to go.  Right now I send an array of all my main level's batchnode's children to each of the children, so they can check for collisions and so on.  I'm thinking a better way would be to make different arrays with the different child types, and keep them in a dictionary that I send to each child.  They can then just grab the array for the key that's interesting to them.

Comment: That's possible too but there's one potential problem: you will have to release the arrays/dictionaries holding nodes in a node's -(void) cleanup method. Because as long as you're holding on to the nodes, the node's dealloc method won't be called. If you try to release the node array/dictionary in dealloc, well then you're going to leak memory.